# How to calculate distance between vertex of two 4-dimensional cube?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, euclidean-geometry, rotations

Consider two $4$-dimensional cube of unit side are adjacent (the intersection of them is a common edge).

> How to calculate distance between vertices of this two cube?

Because this two $4$-cube has equal height, so we can project it into three dimension by canceling height. therefore the result becomes two $3$-cube with one common vertex. Next step I don't know how to measure distance between vertices?

Comment: Remember how you extended Pythagorean theorem into 3 dimensions from 2. Then try to do the same into 4 dimensions. Do not worry about projecting it into 3 dimensional space.